# How to Find Circular References in CTE between Parent/Child tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have a CTE to show dependency tree over 2 tables (a parent and a child table).
There is a data problem resulting in a circular dependency, resulting in a Max Recursion level error being thrown.
i.e.

```
Table: Parent
Id
ItemId

Table: Child
Id
ParentId
ItemId

Example Circular Ref data
Table: Parent
Id   ItemId
1    A
2    B

Table: Child
Id   ParentId  ItemId
1    1         B
2    2         A
```

There are thousands of rows in these tables. How can I write a query identify the offending reference? Or is there a way to set the Max Recursion level that will then just stop the CTE once hit instead of throw an error...then I could view the results and identify the problem child.

```
WITH Recursive_CTE AS 
(
    SELECT        
        ItemId, 
        CAST(ItemDescription AS varchar(100)) AS ItemDescription, 
        Qty, 
        CAST(ParentItemId AS SmallInt) AS ParentItemId, 
        CAST(ItemId AS varchar(100)) AS ParentGroupItemId, 
        CAST('   -' AS varchar(100)) AS LVL, 
        CAST(ItemId AS varchar(100)) AS HierarchyItem, 
        CAST(SKU AS varchar(100)) AS HierarchySKU, 
        CAST(ItemDescription AS varchar(100)) AS HierarchyName, 
        0 AS RecursionLevel
    FROM dbo.vw_BOM AS child
    WHERE (ParentItemId = 0) 
    --and ItemId = @BOMHeaderItemId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT        
        child.ItemId, 
        CAST(parent.LVL + child.ItemDescription AS varchar(100)) AS ItemDescription, 
        child.Qty, 
        CAST(child.ParentItemId AS SmallInt) AS ParentItemId, 
        parent.ParentGroupItemId, 
        CAST('   -' + parent.LVL AS varchar(100)) AS LVL, 
        CAST(parent.HierarchyItem + ':' + CAST(child.ItemId AS varchar(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS HierarchyItem,
        CAST(parent.HierarchySKU + ':' + CAST(child.SKU AS varchar(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS HierarchySKU, 
        CAST(parent.HierarchyName + '/' + CAST(child.ItemDescription AS varchar(100)) AS varchar(100)) AS HierarchyName, 
        parent.RecursionLevel + 1 AS RecursionLevel
    FROM Recursive_CTE AS parent INNER JOIN
            dbo.vw_BOM AS child ON child.ParentItemId = parent.ItemId
)

SELECT        
    Recursive_CTE_1.RecursionLevel, 
    Recursive_CTE_1.ParentGroupItemId, 
    Recursive_CTE_1.ParentItemId, 
    Recursive_CTE_1.ItemId, 
    Recursive_CTE_1.Qty, 
    DATALENGTH(Recursive_CTE_1.LVL) AS LVLLength,
    Recursive_CTE_1.ItemDescription, 
    item.SKU, 
    item.OnHandQty, 
    item.AllocQty, 
    item.AvailableQty, 
    item.ToBeReceivedQty, 
    item.AvailableWFutureQty,   
    Recursive_CTE_1.HierarchyItem, 
    Recursive_CTE_1.HierarchySKU, 
    Recursive_CTE_1.HierarchyName
FROM Recursive_CTE AS Recursive_CTE_1 INNER JOIN
        dbo.vw_ItemInventorySummary AS item ON Recursive_CTE_1.ItemId = item.Id
ORDER BY Recursive_CTE_1.HierarchySKU
option (maxrecursion 200)
```

The View vw_BOM

```
SELECT        dbo.BillOfMaterialHeader.Id AS Id, dbo.BillOfMaterialHeader.ItemId AS ItemId, 0 AS ParentItemId, FGItems.SKU AS SKU, FGItems.SKU + N': ' + FGItems.ShortDescription AS ItemDescription, 
                         dbo.BillOfMaterialHeader.Quantity AS Qty
FROM            dbo.BillOfMaterialHeader INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Items AS FGItems ON dbo.BillOfMaterialHeader.ItemId = FGItems.Id
UNION ALL
SELECT        dbo.BillOfMaterialDetail.Id AS Id, dbo.BillOfMaterialDetail.ItemId AS ItemId, BOMHdr.ItemId AS ParentItemId, RMItems.SKU AS SKU, RMItems.SKU + N': ' + RMItems.ShortDescription AS ItemDescription, 
                         dbo.BillOfMaterialDetail.Quantity AS Qty
FROM            dbo.Items AS RMItems INNER JOIN
                         dbo.BillOfMaterialDetail ON RMItems.Id = dbo.BillOfMaterialDetail.ItemId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.BillOfMaterialHeader BOMHdr ON dbo.BillOfMaterialDetail.BillOfMaterialHeaderId = BOMHdr.Id
```

**UPDATE**

Tab's answer pointed me in the right direction. I used the flattened Parent Child table in vw_BOM and then joined it to itself per Tab's answer, which showed me where 6 Items had the same Item Id in the Parent Table and the Child Table.
Like so:

```
SELECT        dbo.vw_BOM.SKU AS ParentSKU, vw_BOM_1.SKU AS ChildSKU
FROM            dbo.vw_BOM INNER JOIN
                         dbo.vw_BOM AS vw_BOM_1 ON dbo.vw_BOM.ItemId = vw_BOM_1.ParentItemId AND dbo.vw_BOM.ParentItemId = vw_BOM_1.ItemId
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure and  current query?   I can't imagine how you're getting Max Recursion errors from a two-table parent-child structure.

Comment: @TabAlleman Tab, I added the table structure. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: @ChadRichardson, when you see that error actually you can also see the result of a select and you will see in the end what rows give you issue.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks Giorgi, but it is not for me in SSMS, the results tab doesn't have any rows and the messages tab shows that Max recursion error.

Comment: @ChadRichardson, can you show the query?

Comment: Query looks ok. I had similar problem in my table and recursive cte show me the data after the error. Can you try maxrecursion 0? And stop the query manually?

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the CREATE statement for vw_BOM.   You're doing the recursion treating the view as a single table, instead of a two-table query as your question originally led me to believe.   I think the problem is that where you are joining on ItemID, you should be joining on Child.ParentID = Parent.ID

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I tried maxrecursion 0 and manually stopping, but there is no results tab in that case to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CTE already has a hierarchy with the ItemID path concatenated. How about using that to determine if the item has already been seen?

Add a new column to the anchor portion of your CTE, `HasCycle = Convert(bit, 0)`.

Then in the recursive portion of your CTE, add the column and a condition in the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
...
UNION ALL
SELECT
   ... other columns,
   HasCycle = Convert(bit,
      CASE
          WHEN ':' + parent.HierarchyItem + ':' LIKE
             '%:' + Convert(varchar(100), child.ItemID) + ':%'
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
      END)
FROM
   ...
WHERE
   ...
   AND parent.HasCycle = 0 --terminate after cycle is found
;
```

Then you can select from the recursive CTE `WHERE HasCycle = 1` and see all the rows that begin a cycle and their exact path upwards in the `HierarchyItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple self-join should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2
  ON t1.Parent=t2.Child
  AND t1.Child=t2.Parent
```

Comment: You can not do like this. Circular reference may appear through several levels.

Comment: True, the original question led me to believe there were only two levels.

Comment: But it did help me identify some of the issues, where the parent table and its direct descendent had the same ItemId. But likely there are other more complex circular references as well.

Comment: You just saved my friday :)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen these issues before and have resorted to adding items one level at a time, ignoring those seen before.